# Third Party API integration with Apache Flink

Tags: linux, centos, apache-flink

- I am developing a connector for Apache Flink. Within this connector, I have embedded a third-party API that is responsible to communicate with some system services installed on the node. These system services are belong to the root user.
- How can I run Apache Flink jobs that use my connector and allow these jobs root permissions in order for the connector to be able to use the embedded API?
- I am running CentOS 7

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you start your Flink cluster with root privileges, then your job should be executed with root privileges as well. However, I wouldn't really recommend this because this will allow your Flink job to basically change everything on your nodes.